# How to avoid 504 Gateway Timeout error when downloading a big file

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I have a web app with a *Download* button that when being clicked on, requests the server to zip many files into a single zip file and then download the big (2GB) zip file.
The back-end uses nginx as reverse proxy and Flask.

My current client implementation uses XMLHttpRequest (see code below). 
If the file size is small it succeeds but if the file is big, I get a *504 Gateway timeout* error from the server.

I can increase the timeout in my nginx, but I don't know if this is a good solution.
It may solve the problem for 2GB file but what happens if the file becomes 5GB etc..

I have a rough idea of solving the problem by re-implementing the download function using

- more modern approach (e.g. async and fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest)
- manage the big file (maybe use multipart, or Content-Disposetion)

But I don't know exactly how to do that.
Any help or reference to a tutorial / example implementation is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Avi

---

```
    this.saveFromWebServerToZipFile = async function (zipFilename) {

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let queryUrl = MLJ.core.Model.getUrlBase() + 'api/v1_2/download_sites_as_zip';

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", queryUrl, true);
            req.responseType = "blob";
            req.onload = function (event) {
                if (req.status === 200) {
                    var blob = req.response;
                    let fileName = 'zippedFiles.zip';
                    console.log('fileName', fileName); 
                    let link=document.createElement('a');
                    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download=fileName;
                    link.click();
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else {
                    reject(req);
                }
            };

            req.send();
        });
    };
```